# gnuplot data dgrid3d changes circle to square

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I have unstructured data in my file, thats really long. I want to create a coloured pm3d graph. from what I understand, i have to interpolate the data with set dgrid3d. However if I do that, my data points which are on a circular xy Area are interpolated to a square. Any idea how to avoid this? Sorting the data in the file by hand is no option...

Answer (score 0):

by default, `dgrid3d` puts everything on a 10x10 grid which is pretty sparse.  You can increase the resolution simply by doing:

```
 set dgrid3d 100,100
```

Not that at each gridpoint (100000 in this case) requires a sum over your entire dataset leading to an algorithm that is `O(nx*ny*N)` where nx,ny are the number of points in the dgrid3d and N is the number of datapoints in your file.  (In other words, this can take a while ;))